# Why didn't I get reputation change for accepting an answer?

Tags: support, reputation

I accepted an answer to my question, but my rep didn't get changed. why?

Answer (score 6):

Because you accepted a CW answer. CW answers don't earn their posters any reputation for getting accepted, so it won't earn you any reputation for accepting it.